# One non-root user run jetty by port 512 which less that port1024

Tags: linux, bind, setcap

Customer asks us to create a non-root user to run our web system which bind port 512, less than 1024. When web server([jetty](http://www.eclipse.org/jetty/)) runs, this is the exception:

```
2013-10-16 14:49:51.406:WARN::failed Server@2c2893ce: java.net.SocketException: Permission denied
2013-10-16 14:49:51.406:WARN::EXCEPTION
java.net.SocketException: Permission denied
        at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind0(Native Method)
        at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Net.java:444)
        at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Net.java:436)
        at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketChannelImpl.bind(ServerSocketChannelImpl.java:214)
```

So I found out some solutions about how non-root user bind port less than 1024, at last the solution i used was set "cap_net_bind_service" to java, by set Capabilities, the command is:

```
sudo setcap cap_net_bind_service+eip /usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.7.0_25/bin/java
```

But when i start jetty again, another error happens:

```
[admin@VPRCEMSUSOFC04 bin]$ ./jetty.sh start
Starting Jetty: /usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.7.0_25/bin/java: error while loading shared libraries: libjli.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

Even when I execute `java -version`, it also causes an exception:

```
[admin@VPRCEMSUSOFC04 bin]$ java -version
java: error while loading shared libraries: libjli.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

But when I login with root, it`s fine:

```
[root@VPRCEMSUSOFC04 etc]# java -version
java version "1.7.0_25"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_25-b15)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 23.25-b01, mixed mode)
```

I can`t understand why this happen. Why there are two different results under root and non-root user. It seems that set Capabilities impact this.

The Linux kernel is 2.6.32-220.el6.x86_64. OS is Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 6.2 (Santiago).

Answer (score 2):

The Java executable relies on a feature that is [disabled by the kernel when the executable acquires additional permissions or capabilities](http://blog.tinola.com/?e=7), as a safety measure. If you want to use this executable as non-root then you'll need to add the location of libjli.so to your loader configuration, located in `/etc/ld.so.conf*`.

Comment: Thanks, Ignacio. it`s cool. I take this way and work fine.